# Copying a Solution folder and renaming all files and subfolders

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution

I have a Solution X. In windows explorer this is the solution folder:

[image]

I want to keep X as it is but use all its functionality (and winforms) in a new Solution Y.
I copied the whole solution folder ao X and renamed the folder Y.
In VS I used the solution explorer and renamed the solution to Y and also renamed the project to Y.

So in the Solution Explorer it looks like the following:

[image]

And in Windows explorer I've now got:

[image]

You can see from the above that there are still Xs. If I manually rename these files/folders in windows explorer then, when opening the solution in VS it complains about not being able to find certain files.

Is the above a bad practise to be avoided?

Or is there an easy way to ensure renaming *washes through* all the files/folders in the solution folder without confusing VS?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bad idea.  Why do you need to rename all the folders?  You should only need to rename the top one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I realise the functionality isn't impacted by a few files being called X so _really its more just for tidyness_ - if in the future I go to the folder Y and there are subfolders/files in there called X then it'll be confusing. I can just create a blank solution and import existing classes and rename then quite painlessly ....its the winforms that is the problem

Comment: You'll have to do the folder renaming in VS when you open the copied project, so that VS is aware of your name changes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've right-clicked & renamend everything I can see in the Solution Explorer but still when I go to Windows explorer there are files/folders called X

Comment: It sounds like they are not part of the solution/project, or you didn't put them back to their original names before changing them in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something I'd recommend doing, generally.

If you really need to then I'd suggest that you copy the solution, open it in Visual Studio, and rename the folders through the Solution Explorer.  This way, the solution file is updated with the new folder names and you won't see those errors.

Comment: Alright Dan - I am doing this but it doesn't reflect in all the solution folder names. I've added a couple of screen prints to show the situation. The folder that has the directories `bin` and `obj` in it are still under the old name.

Comment: Those folders would have to be renamed manually in Explorer, and then you'll have to remove and re-add all of the projects to the solution (or manually edit the solution file).

Comment: Ok that worked Dan - although I think I'll be better avoiding having to do this in the future. The namespace in the project is still called _X_; is it a case of doing a find/replace to change the name of the namespace ... or is there a tool build into VS to accomplish this?

Comment: Some refactoring tools will help you with this - I'm not sure about Visual Studio's inbuilt stuff, but the DevExpress refactor tool will definitely help.  It's still going to be painful though...

Comment: ...find/replace is not recommended? or actually - find/replace is not guaranteed to work?

Comment: Not guaranteed to work.  I'd be wary of using any tool that's not aware of the syntax.